# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, matplotlib, dll, pip, importerror

Today, I tried installing matplotlib to learn about it. First, I have to say that my python version was 3.11.4. I first upgraded pip by the command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

It has upgraded pip to pip 23.2.1. Then, I installed the matplotlib by the command:

```
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

After the process had finished, I tried to check if it works. First, I typed `python` in the command line and after that, I typed import matplotlib. Here's the traceback I got:

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 236, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._cext import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried uninstalling matplotlib and installing it again. Then I tried checking its dependency and upgrading the packages it requires, but it wouldn't work. Also, I tried adding matplotlib to the path after the suggestion from ChatGPT, but I deleted it after I saw it wouldn't work. After that, I tried uninstalling python from my PC and removing all the remnants. Next, I installed the newest version of python, but it didn't change the results.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC runtime is currently a dependency of matplotlib and the required DLL should be distributed with the wheel. Run:

```
pip install msvc-runtime
```

the import works, maybe that package or something like it could be a transient OS-specific dependency.

Comment: for me, it says: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement msvc-runtime`. (pip 23.3.2) (python 3.12)

Comment: I still get the same error